# Intersection of 2 dynamically allocated arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create a function that will find the intersection of two dynamically allocated arrays comparing array 1 to array 2. For any values in array 1 that are not in array 2, those values should be deleted in array 1 so that array 1 now only holds the common values of both arrays (no repeats). I cannot use vectors, hashes, or any other thing outside of my current functions in my class:

here is my code so far:

```
bool IntSet::contains(int val) const
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
{
    if (set[i] == val)
        return true;
}
return false;
}
```

this function compares an integer parameter to values currently stored in the array...if a value is in the array it returns true and if else false;

this next function takes in a value and removes that value from the array:

```
void IntSet::remove(int val)
{
for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
{
    if (set[i] == val)
        for (int j = 0; j < numValues; j++)
            set[j] = set[j + 1];
}
numValues--;
}
```

here's where I've been having problems, this next function is supposed to iterate through one array and compare those values with the values in the other array...if one value from one array is in the other, it should just skip it, but if a value is not in the array calling the function, it should delete that value from the calling array:

```
void IntSet::removeDifferent(const IntSet &set2)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < set2.size(); i++)
  {
    if (!set2.contains(set[i]))
    {
        remove(set[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

ive tried about 50 different variations on the removeDifferent() function and I just can't seem to figure this one out. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If this isn't homework then [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

Comment: @user657267 He said "I cannot use vectors, hashes, or any other thing outside of my current functions in my class"

Comment: this is indeed homework...sorry, I didn't make it clear in my question, but we can only use other functions defined in our current class, mainly the other 2 i have listed above my removeDifferent() function

Comment: The `remove` function has a number of problems, including indexing beyond the end of the array. A good approach is to create a set of test cases, and write up code that checks those cases automatically, called a **unit test**. Then after each change of code, run the unit test.

Comment: A fairly general way to find common values is to sort the arrays. You can alternatively do it with raw brute force checking each value of one array against every value of the other, but then the time to do it increases with the square of the array size.

Comment: `set2.size()` should be `size()` in `removeDifferent`?

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating `i` through the indexes of `set2`, but then you're testing `set[i]`. Try this:

```
void IntSet::removeDifferent(const IntSet &set2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numValues; ) {
        if (!set2.contains(set[i])) {
            remove(set[i]);
        } else {
            i++;
    }
}
```

Note that I also removed `i++` from the `for` loop header. This is because when you remove an element, all the following elements are shifted down, so the next element takes its place in the array. If you incremented `i`, it would skip that element.

You also need to fix `remove`. It should start its inner loop from `i`, so it only shifts down the elements after the one being removed, and it should stop at `numValues-1`, so it doesn't try to access outside the array when it copies `set[j+1]`. And as an optimization, it can `break` out of the outer loop once it has found a match (I assume `IntSet` doesn't allow duplicates, since you only decrement `numValues` by 1).

```
void IntSet::remove(int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
    {
        if (set[i] == val) {
            for (int j = i; j < numValues - 1; j++) {
                set[j] = set[j + 1];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    numValues--;
}
```

Comment: again, I feel silly for not realizing this mistake sooner, thank you so much for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your remove() function:

```
void IntSet::remove(int val)
{
for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
{
    if (set[i] == val)
        for (int j = 0; j < numValues; j++)
            set[j] = set[j + 1];
}
numValues--;
}
```

You can figure out yourself why this is wrong by using a paper and pencil here. Start with a typical example: let's say you found the value you're looking for in the third element of a five-element array:

```
if (set[i] == val)
```

In this example, `i` would be set to 2, and `numValues` would be set to five. It doesn't matter what `val` is. Whatever it is, you found it when `i` is 2, and `numValues` is five: you found it in the third element of a five element array. Keep that in mind.

Now, you know that you are now supposed to remove the third element in this five element array. But what do you think will happen next:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < numValues; j++)
            set[j] = set[j + 1];
```

Well, using the aforementioned paper and pencil, if you work it out, the following will happen:

- set[1] will be copied to set[0]
- set[2] will be copied to set[1]
- set[3] will be copied to set[2]
- set[4] will be copied to set[3]
- set[5] will be copied to set[4]

There are two problems here:

A) There is no `set[5]`. Recall that this is a five-element array, si you only have `set[0]` through `set[4]`

B) You're not supposed to copy everything in array down to one element. You have to copy only the elements *after* the element you want to remove.

Fix these two problems, and you will probably find that everything will work correctly.

Comment: wow, i feel so silly for not realizing this earlier. I was convinced it had to be something else that was wrong. Looking at it now I understand completely. Thanks again!